# Monit: keep record of all test results

Tags: logging, monit

My apache server is frequently spawning lots of children.  I think there's multiple causes and while I pick them apart, I've band-aided the situation by getting monit to restart services when it spots the problem.

One thing that would help is a historical record of load averages.  I considered running a cron job, but then this seems silly when monit is already doing that.  Is there some way to make monit record *everything* it knows about the state of the system?  Not just for this situation but for other problems I've had in the past: disk space, server status etc.

Looking at the monit documentation, it does have a log file and it does have a web service.  But I can't find a configuration option to turn on detailed historical logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [M/Monit](http://mmonit.com) to do this.

[image]

Comment: Fair enough.  I'll try out the paid version.